# Calling a function with an XML file as input parameter

Tags: c#, xml

I have created a WCF service in which I have created the following method

```
public List<AddTravelDetails> ReadXML(XmlDocument xDoc)
```

Now I want to consume the service. 
Can anyone help me? How can I pass `XmlDocument` as input parameter for the `ReadXML` function?

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you wondering how to assign a document to the xDoc variable?

Comment: Yes, I want to assign document to xDoc variable.

Comment: Does your document already exist on file somewhere or do you still have to create it in your code?

Comment: The document is saved in my D drive in .xml format

Comment: Why would you want to input raw XML into a service method? This renders WSDL and XSD useless, because the user can input anything they like. Can't you build a DataContract from the expected input and parse the XML on the client side into this DataContract? Besides that an XmlDocument just is a wrapper around an input string, **if you really must do that** then just use a `string` parameter and create the `XmlDocument` inside the service method with that string as input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(pathToYourFile);
```

Where pathToYourFile is for example: `@"D:\yourfile.xml"`